# How to spawn a QRect when I press a Mousebutton?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to spawn a Bullet (QRect) when the left-mousebutton is pressed.

The only thing you can do at the moment is moving and rotating the QRect "Spieler".
I hope you can help me and explain how to do this.

This is where I draw my QRect "Spieler0", Spieler is german for Player.

```
void Shooter::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * p)
{
QRect Spieler0 (Spieler0X,Spieler0Y,SpielerBreite,SpielerHoehe);
//QRect Kugel    (Spieler0X+50,Spieler0Y+50,5,5);
QPainter paint(this);
paint.translate(Spieler0X + SpielerBreite/2,Spieler0Y+SpielerHoehe/2);
paint.rotate(Grad);
paint.translate(-Spieler0X-SpielerBreite/2,-Spieler0Y-SpielerHoehe/2);
paint.drawRect(Spieler0);
//paint.drawRect(Kugel);

update();
}
```

And this is my QMousePressEvent, what do I have to do to make it paint Bullets everytime I press the MouseButton.

```
void Shooter::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *n)
{
     if(n->button()==Qt::LeftButton){

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a member to your class that holds the spawned bullets.
Put this into your shooter.h file in the private section:

```
QList<QRect> m_kugeln;
```

This way the bullets information is kept as long as the class exists.

In your mousePressEvent function add this line to add a bullet to the list on mouseclick

```
m_kugeln.append(QRect(Spieler0X + 50, Spieler0Y + 50, 5, 5));
```

Put this into your paintEvent class to draw all bullets:

```
for (auto kugel : m_kugeln)
{
    paint.drawRect(kugel);
}
```

Code not tested, but should work.
When something is not clear feel free to ask.

Viel Spaß noch beim lernen! :)

Edit: If you want to delete the bullets once they are offscreen you could use use one of these functions:

```
m_kugeln.removeOne()
m_kugeln.removeAt()
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I tried it but the ".append" function has no idea what it should do with an int. Could you help me again?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You have to pass a QRect to the list.
m_kugeln.append(QRect(Spieler0X + 50, Spieler0Y + 50, 5, 5));